# Bottom button in xamarin android activity is not displaying

Tags: mono, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I want to add btton(button1) at the bottom of screen ,whish will be displayed always.,regardless of anount of data inside scrollview.
My button1 is not displaying at the bottom of the screen.
Anyone know,where I am mistaken?

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:background="#ffffffff">
      <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center">
            <TextView
                     android:text="Step 1"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:id="@+id/step1TextView"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                     android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                     android:textStyle="normal"
                     android:textColor="#ff000000"
                     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
            <TextView
                    android:text="Step 2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/step2TextView"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#ff000000"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/step1TextView"
                    android:gravity="center" />
           <TextView
                    android:text="Step 3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/step3TextView"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    android:textColor="#ff000000"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/step2TextView"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true" />
           <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#ffffffff"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/step1TextView">
                    <RelativeLayout
                              android:id="@+id/highlightFooter1Layout"
                              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                              android:layout_height="10dp"
                              android:background="#ffffffff">
                              <LinearLayout
                                        android:id="@+id/highlightFooter11Layout"
                                         android:layout_width="2dp"
                                         android:layout_height="70dp"
                                         android:background="#ffe9e9e9"
                                         android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                                         android:layout_marginRight="30dp" />
                             <LinearLayout
                                         android:id="@+id/highlightFooter12Layout"
                                         android:layout_width="2dp"
                                         android:layout_height="70dp"
                                         android:background="#000000"
                                         android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                                         android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                                      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/highlightFooter11Layout" />
                            <LinearLayout
                                         android:id="@+id/highlightFooter13Layout"
                                         android:layout_width="2dp"
                                         android:layout_height="70dp"
                                         android:background="#ffe9e9e9"
                                         android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                                         android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                                       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/highlightFooter12Layout" />
                      </RelativeLayout>
                      <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/highlightFooter2Layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="#ffe9e9e9"
            android:layout_below="@+id/highlightFooter1Layout">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/highlightFooter21Layout"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:background="#ffff8b03"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="65dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:text="Your phone number has been successfully verified . Please enter the following details to begin."
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="#ffffffff"
            android:textColor="#ff000000" />
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/stateSpinner"
            android:background="#ffe9e9e9"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/districtSpinner"
            android:background="#ffe9e9e9"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/constSpinner"
            android:background="#ffe9e9e9"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <EditText
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="#ffe9e9e9" />
        <ImageView
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Chief Minister"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/cmTextView"
            android:gravity="center" />
        <TextView
            android:text="cm name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/cmNametextView"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#ffff8b03" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Member of Parliament"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/mpTextView"
            android:gravity="center" />
        <TextView
            android:text="mp name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/mpNameTextView"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#ffff8b03" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Member of Legislative Assembly"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/mlaTextView"
            android:gravity="center" />
        <TextView
            android:text="mla name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/mlaNameTextView"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#ffff8b03" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <Button
        android:text="Next"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:background="#ffff8b03"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:maxHeight="50dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Add </LinearLayout> at the end of your xml atleast just to close it :) If that doesn't help i would start removing each layout one by one.

Comment: sorry @Casper Skoubo , your comment worken for me but I have undone vote to your comment by mistake.I am extremely sorry.

Comment: No problem, you got it fixed, so thats cool to me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Casper suggested add the `</LinearLayout>` at the end of your xml and add `android:layout_weight="1"` to you `ScrollView` and remove it from `LinearLayout` with your button.